# How to move the existing folders to another new folder in thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, ubuntu-14.04, email-filter

I'm using the Thunderbird for mail. I'm getting many emails so I created some folders and wrote the filter for that. It also works fine (it is filtering my mails and move it to corresponding folders).

The issue is now I have many folders, So I plan to create a new folder and move this existing folders as subfolders to the newly created folder. But I can't achieve it.

For example:
**Existing folder with filters**

> Cprogramming
>
> DataStructure
>
> RDBMS
>
> Perl
>
> PHP

**New Folder**

> Studies

Now I need to move all the existing folders with filters to the `Studies` folder. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I removed the waffle and corrected the language a little. +1 from me

Comment: Can you move folders without filters as subfolders to a new folder? Is your problem caused by the filters?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do that, I try to drag and drop and also Cut and Paste. but it doesn't work for me.